# C# doubt in GetType, Managed CodeGen

Tags: c#

Consider the code,

```
Type t0 = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.dll");
Type t1 = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Font");
```

Here in order to find type of "System.Drawing.Font" the assembly "System.Drawing.dll" is needed. how to use it.?

i.e wat if i do, so that value of **t0** wont be null.??

Consider i ave a dll, **proj.dll** and i need to find the type of the class **Class1** that is present in the dll.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically add .dll and then do something with it?

Comment: actually i want to add a class library dll and get the type of the class in the dll.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the assembly, including the version number for strongly named assemblies:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Font,System.Drawing,"+
                      " Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, "+
                      "PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
```

Of course, if it's *really* just `System.Drawing.Font` (or another type you know at compile-time), use `typeof`:

```
Type t = typeof(System.Drawing.Font);
```

If you know another type in the same assembly at compile-time, you can use [`Assembly.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx):

```
Type sizeType = typeof(System.Drawing.Size);
Assembly assembly = sizeType.Assembly;
Type fontType = assembly.GetType("System.Drawing.Font");
```

Comment: Type t = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Font,System.Drawing");

retruns values NULL to t..??? how to solve it.

Comment: You need the specify the full name of the assembly, including version and public key. If you use the line that Jon posted in his answer, it should work.

Comment: @Andy: The first version of my answer didn't have the version in. I suspected it was necessary, but didn't know it offhand. I posted a quick response indicating that, and then wrote the little test app.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the strong name of the assembly to load it, and then load the type from it, like

```
  Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
            Type font = asm.GetType("System.Drawing.Font");
```

Comment: thanks. what if i want to add a class library dll and get the type of a class in the dll..?
how to add that dll and find its Version,sulture and public key token.?

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`System.Reflection.Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) method.